# An implementation of a custom interface identical to the Java method iterator() is not working

Tags: java, iterator

I am attempting to implement an interface that is identical to the `iterator()` method found in Java. For my specific program, the interface is implemented as an inner class `PriorityQueueIterator` to the outer class `PriorityQueueLinked`. It has methods `hasNext()` and `next()` just like in `iterator()` and it's design is to iterate through elements of a linked list Priority Queue. What the implementation should be outputting is all the elements within the passed Priority Queue, however, I am only getting the first element of the Priority Queue as an output. Below is the snippet of code:

```
 public Iterator iterator() {
  return new PriorityQueueIterator(this);
}

class PriorityQueueIterator implements Iterator<Object> {
  
  private Queue<PriorityQueueLinked> q = new LinkedList<PriorityQueueLinked>();
  
  public PriorityQueueIterator(PriorityQueueLinked pq) {
      if(pq.isEmpty()) {
          return;
      }
      else {
          q.add(pq);
      }
  }
  
  public boolean hasNext() {
      return !q.isEmpty();
  }
  
  public Object next() {
      if(hasNext()) {
          PriorityQueueLinked pq = q.remove();
          Object o = new Object();
          if(!pq.isEmpty()) {
              // examine() retrieves the element at the front of the Priority Queue
              o = pq.examine();
          }
          return o;
      }
      else {
          throw new OutOfBounds("No elements in queue.");
      }
  }
}
```

In the `main(String[] args)` method:

```
PriorityQueueIterator it = PriorityQueueLinked.PriorityQueueIterator(PriorityQueue);
while (it.hasNext()) {
     System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

If I passed a Priority Queue which had an element structure: 6, 9, 1 (note, the commas are only used here to show the separation of elements and in effect the individual links), the output should be `6 9 1`. However, I am getting an output of `6`. How should I fix this?

Comment: You have a queue, elements of which are queues themselves. When you call `next` on the outer queue you take the next element from q, which is an inner queue and then return the first element of this inner queue. After that the outer queue q is empty, because you removed from it the whole inner queue.